# Flask Css file doesn't work even after reload

Tags: python, css, flask

I have been stuck with this for hours, and haven't found an answer anywhere...
I am creating a simple web app with python+flask and i want to apply styling for my page, but it simply doesn't work, and there is no error.
Directories are as follows
[style.css  is in static folder, profile.html in templates folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG73j.png)

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/profile/<name>')
def profile(name):
     return render_template("profile.html",name=name)
if __name__=="__main__":
     app.run(debug=True)
```

That is the code from app.py file.

Now my html looks like this.

```
<!doctype html>
<title> Welcome </title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" herf="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}" />
<h1>Hey there YOU {{name}}</h1>
```

I was looking up on the internet for solutions, and usualy, the problem is in the link, or browser cache. I tried reloading brower, opening with different browers and so on, but it doesn't seem to help...

Also my css file if needed...

```
h1 {
     padding: 100px;
     color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've mistyped the `href` attribute in `<link>`. It should be `href` but you've typed `herf` instead.

Little tip for next time: open the `Network` tab of your browser's dev tools and check that all the assets you need/expect are 1) fetched and 2) fetched successfully.

You can also look into adopting an editor that will warn you of typos like these.

Comment: Oh my god thank you ! Such a dumb mistake , it works now :D

Comment: Ha, don't worry, we've all been there. Say hi! to  `<script href="">` and `<link src="">` from me when you see them... ;)